# Is it possible to obtain the symbolic expression for the maximum value of a function?

Tags: functions, maximum

Is it possible to obtain the symbolic expression for the maximum value of `out` as a function of `A`,`R`, `C1`, and `T`? The plot is a check for an example case using some typical values.

```
Nano = 10^-9;
Milli = 10^-3;
value = {A -> 1, T -> 1/1000, R -> 1000};
$Assumptions = 
  Element[{t, R, C1, T, t}, Reals] && t > 0 && R > 0 && C1 > 0 && 
   T > 0;
H = 1/(s C1)/(R + 1/(s C1));
IN = LaplaceTransform[
   A Sin[(2 Pi)/T t]*(UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[t - T/2]), t, s];
out = InverseLaplaceTransform[H*IN, s, t];
func = Table[
   out /. value, {C1, {16 Nano, 80 Nano, 160 Nano, 330 Nano}}];
Plot[func, {t, 0, 2 Milli}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Since your function looks "nice" and smooth and doesn't have a denominator going through zero, think about finding where the derivative of your function == 0. Will that be where your maximum is?

Comment: @Bill I tried that but finding where the derivative of your function == 0 is still difficult.

Comment: If I use the code you provided, I get a different plot than the one you provided ... Can you double check you pasted the right code? Also, take a look at [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html).

Comment: @Domen what did you get? I just tried again and still got the same result.

Comment: Something seems wrong. With `A=1` `Simplify[D[out,t],T>0&&R>0&&C1>0]` is exponentially decreasing and does not increase to a max and then decrease.  Can you edit your post to show your use of `D` to look for a zero?

Comment: You probably have some variables defined from before. Clear all variables with ``Clear["Global`*"]``, or restart the kernel with ``Quit[]``, then reevaluate the code again. You should get [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STD3m.png).

Comment: @Domen That's strange. I quit the kernel and tried again, but still got the same result. The waveform is from a circuit, and the simulation also produced the same result. 
https://ibb.co/9rqszC6

Comment: @Bill this is the derivative. I'm not sure if I should add it to the post. 
https://ibb.co/HDrPx6s

Comment: I fixed your code. It should be ``$Assumptions``, not ``assumption``. Now I get the same result.

Comment: In the final expression ``out``, there are terms with ``HeavisideTheta``. I _think_ you can remove them because they should not affect the position of maximum, which appears at $t<T/2$: ``outS = FullSimplify[out /. HeavisideTheta[_] -> 0]``. However, Mathematica still cannot find the maximum (``Maximize[outS, t]``), and it might not be even possible (look at the structure of corresponding equation ``D[outS, t] == 0``).

Comment: @Domen Yes, I tried that too, but I still didn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

piecewise derivative

```
out /. value  /. C1 -> c1 Nano // Simplify
{Simplify[%, t < 1/2000], Simplify[%, t > 1/2000]}
null = D[%, t]  (* derivative *)
```

$$\left\{\frac{500 \left(-1000000 \pi  e^{-\frac{1000000 t}{\text{c1}}}+2000 \pi ^2 \text{c1} \sin (2000 \pi 
   t)+1000000 \pi  \cos (2000 \pi  t)\right)}{\pi ^2 \text{c1}^2+250000},-\frac{500000000 \pi 
   \left(e^{500/\text{c1}}+1\right) e^{-\frac{1000000 t}{\text{c1}}}}{\pi ^2 \text{c1}^2+250000}\right\}$$

only for first part `t<1/2000` maximum exists:

```
ContourPlot[null[[1]] == 0, {t, 0, .0005}, {c1, 10, 350}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "C1/Nano"}]
```

[image]

Perhaps `FindFormula` might give you an idea about the symbolic function you are looking for!